# Problem in dualbooting

Tags: system-installation

I am having new 4th generation HP 15-n004TX laptop. I am unable to do dual booting ubuntu on Windows 8. Whenever I try to load windows 8 from Grub loader its getting crash so please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your problem is being caused by Secure Boot which is a new Win8 feature. You can start with disabling Secure Boot while looking for a better solution with an SB-compatible Linux loader. Check this thread: [GRUB UEFI windows boot fail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377127/grub-uefi-windows-boot-fail/377168#377168)

P.S. What is a "4th generation laptop"? )

Comment: He probably means a 4th generation processor. I guess.