# Can't dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 8.1

Tags: boot, windows, uefi, system-installation

I know this isn't the first time anyone has asked this question , I have looked around but that didn't solve my problem.

I recently purchased Toshiba c-50a , with preinstalled Windows 8.1. When I enable UEFI mode in setup , it boots directly into windows and I can't boot my USB Ubuntu installation.

If however I change from UEFI to CMS, I boot into ubuntu and install it (without it recognizing windows 8.1), but in the grub 2 menu option it doesn't display Windows at all. I tried boot-repair, but it says "you are in legacy mode, change to uefi". If i change to uefi , I boot directly to windows. I still continued using boot-repair, but it ended with error and corrupted grub2. I am currently trying to repair it in Live Disc.
Any solutions would be appreciated.

---

This is the error message after boot-repair :

```
An error occurred during the repair.

A new file (~/Boot-Info_2014-05-08__04h40.txt) will open in your text
viewer.

In case you still experience boot problem, indicate its content to:
boot.repair@gmail.com

You can now reboot your computer.


You may want to retry after deactivating the [Backup and rename
Windows EFI files] option.

The boot of your PC is in Legacy mode. You may want to retry after
changing it to EFI mode.
```

---

I clicked retry after changing the encoding in the text file, still no use. Here are the contents of the text file that opened: http://pastebin.com/bVWrnp3T

Comment: Did you read [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what you are using to install Ubuntu whether it is a cd or usb, but what I have found easiest is to download rufus while in windows 8.1 with whatever flavor of Ubuntu is your favorite.  I recommend Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64. A quick google search will help you find rufus. [But here it is just to be nice (click on this orange text)](http://rufus.akeo.ie/downloads/rufus-1.4.7.exe)

Once you have rufus up and running, insert your usb stick.  Remember your usb stick will lose EVERYTHING on it, so make sure you get anything important off of it first.  I think the smallest you can use is 4 GB but I recommend 8 GB just to be safe.

Select your Ubuntu image down in the middle right portion of the rufus window.

THIS IS THE MOST CRUCIAL PART:
**AFTER** selecting your image, then go back to the top of the rufus window and make sure you select GPT style with uefi.  After that is done, click the create or okay button at the bottom of the window and answer yes to formatting the usb disk.  It will only take rufus about 2 minutes to create your Ubuntu install disk.

Exit rufus and windows...leave all your bios settings the same (uefi mode) and make sure you find out which <kbd>f</kbd> button to press on your keyboard from your manufacturer to select the usb disk as the boot device.

Install Ubuntu as you normally would. Then after installing, to access your Ubuntu install press that same button you pressed to boot from the usb disk but Ubuntu should have updated your efi files in your bios so the boot disk menu will now list Ubuntu with whatever drive description after it.

Ex: ubuntu (Samsung 840 evo 500 GB)

select that disk and Ubuntu will load.

Not as great as the old way of having grub or windows boot loader let you choose without pressing a bunch of buttons but it works.  I am sure someone has a better solution, but I am kind of a noob.  Hope I helped!

Comment: @Danatela how do I format my answers better in the first place?

Comment: @user3574214 please vote it up if it works out for you! I need some rep help...

Comment: I recommend you to read help that shows above editing window. Also, when your posts are edited, check _how_ they were edited. When you reach significant amount of rep (>300), you will have the idea about how to format your posts. The things I did: removed the <pre> tag, removed irrelevant paragraphs (tip: try to keep your posts laconic), did some minor changes. And if you have _specific_ questions about formatting, you are welcome on Meta and in chat (if urgent).

Comment: @user3574214: If this answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Comment: Also, OP can't upvote your answer, he can only accept it. To upvote the posts, users have to reach 15 rep points. If you want your rep to raise quickly, you should write as many good posts as possible. Do not ask for upvoting, it's done by the decision of users.

Comment: @Danatela haha kind of like fishing for compliments...? But I do get points if he excepts my answer right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14394/discussion-between-user175999-and-danatela)

Comment: In theory, after installing Ubuntu in this way, you should see GRUB, which should enable booting either Linux or Windows. If you *don't* see GRUB by default, then something went wrong -- maybe you've got a buggy EFI. There are ways around this problem, and in fact questions and answers here that address such problems, like [this one.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/377127/grub-uefi-windows-boot-fail)

Comment: @Rod Smith Oh I see grub but it is only after following the instructions I put above.